# How do I make a villager trade a spawn egg?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried to make a Villager trade Some stuff for a villager spawn egg, but I end up getting a blank spawn egg... I'm playing on 1.10, and I don't know if it's a bug or something they've changed. I should also mention that I use a generator, Link [Here](https://minecraftcommand.science/shop-generator). Here is the code I used:

**The trade I mentioned is at the bottom**

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {
    Profession: 2,
    CustomName: "Frank",
    CustomNameVisible: 1,
    Career: 1,
    CareerLevel: 42,
    CanPickUpLoot: 0,
    PersistenceRequired: 1,
    Invulnerable: 1,
    Attributes: [
        {
            Name: "generic.maxHealth",
            Base: 99999
        }
    ],
    Offers: {
        Recipes: [
            {
                 buy: {
                     id: "rotten_flesh",
                     Count: 1
                 },
                 buyB: {
                     id: "coal",
                     Count: 1
                 },
                 maxUses: 9999999,
                 sell: {
                     id: "leather",
                     Count: 1
                 },
                 rewardExp: false
            },
            {
                buy: {
                    id: "gunpowder",
                    Count: 2
                },
                buyB: {
                    id: "coal",
                    Count: 2
                },
                maxUses: 9999999,
                sell: {
                    id: "golden_apple",
                    Count: 1
                },
                rewardExp: false
            },
            {
                buy: {
                    id: "gunpowder",
                    Count: 2
                },
                buyB: {
                    id: "coal",
                    Count: 3,
                    Damage: 1
                },
                maxUses: 9999999,
                sell: {
                    id: "golden_apple",
                    Count: 1
                },
                rewardExp: false
            },
            {
                buy: {
                    id: "rotten_flesh",
                    Count: 1
                },
                buyB: {
                    id: "coal",
                    Count: 1,
                    Damage: 1
                },
                maxUses: 9999999,
                sell: {
                    id: "golden_apple",
                    Count: 1
                },
                rewardExp: false
            },
            {
                buy: {
                    id: "rotten_flesh",
                    Count: 64
                },
                buyB: {
                    id: "bone",
                    Count: 32
                },
                maxUses: 9999999,
                sell: {
                    id: "spawn_egg {EntityTag:{id:Villager}}",
                    Count: 1,
                },
                rewardExp: false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I make a villager trade a spawn egg?

Answer (score 4):

> id: "spawn_egg {EntityTag:{id:Villager}}",

The `id` tag is solely for the item ID, any other data should be included as other data tags:

```
sell: {
    id:"spawn_egg",
    Count:1,
    tag: {
        EntityTag: {
            id:"Villager"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since i checked but if i recall correctly, all the spawn eggs are considered variants of the same entity. That means if you give them a "spawn egg" itll simply give a blank one.

you need to specify which one you're giving them. I know its not great but I hope it helps